# kohana (v 3.3) // custom route #userName match controller/method/username

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I want to custom uri routing

www.example.com/*username

match with

controller/methods/username

how to try this one ?

```
Route::set('user','<user>',array('user'=>'/[*]+[a-z]+$/'));
```

please help .. Thanks

Comment: For startes, there is no `#` in your route uri and the regex doesn't make sense to me. Have you read the [documentation on routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing)?

Comment: my wrong ,

i need to make like this 
www.example.com/*username